# How to fix commit history between two branches?

Tags: git, github

I have two branch: `main` and `develop`. `develop` is behind `main` by 1 commit.

So `main` has 3 commits:

```
C1 - C2 - C3
```

I created `develop` branch when `main` was at `C2`. Now I made a series of commits in `develop` and later rebased `main` into `develop` running the command `git rebase main`. Comparing with `main`, the commit graph for `develop` looks like the following,

```
main:        C1 - C2 - C3
develop:     C1 - C2 - C4 - C5 - C3
```

Now, how do I fix `develop` to have the commit history as follows:

```
C1 - C2 - C3 - C4 - C5
```

Comment: Your diagram is wrong. If you merged main into develop, the last commit of develop is not C3. It is a merge commit.

Comment: The situation you described can't happen at all. Commit `C3` is represented with different parents in `main` and `develop`, which can't be. Try to give a better representation of your branches and commits (maybe simply the `git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate` output). Anyway, your solution will probably be an interactive rebase of `develop`

Comment: It sounds like you are merely saying you wish you had rebased develop onto main instead of merging main into develop. That is a perfectly viable thing to do. Just erase the merge commit and do the rebase instead.

Comment: @matt Sorry I meant rebase not merge. My bad. I did rebase and git adds the commit `C3` above `C5` as represented in the diagram. I ran the command `git rebase main`.

Comment: No, the diagram is not a correct representation of what would happen if you rebased either.

Comment: Also your new description of what you did is nonsense. "rebased main into develop running the command git rebase main" No. if you are on develop, `git rebase main` does not "rebase main into develop" (whatever _that_ means). It rebases develop onto main.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would give the situation in your diagram is `cherry-pick`. Even that would not give _exactly_ what you have drawn.

Comment: @matt I think what OP did was merged `main` into `develop`, and then rebased `develop` onto `main`. That could yield the result in the question, and might also explain the edit. (Perhaps OP can confirm.) Either way, your answer should solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to be certain, as your diagram is incoherent, but it sounds like what you mean might be

```
git switch develop
git reset --hard @^1
git rebase main
```

That will give

```
C1 - C2 - C3 (main)
            \
             - C4 - C5 (develop)
```